# Programatic code modification (e.g. variable extraction) in Java

Tags: java, reflection, bytecode-manipulation

I know it's possible to do nice stuff with Reflection, such as invoking methods, or altering the values of fields. Is it possible to do heavier code modification, though, at runtime and programmatically?

For instance, if I have a method:

```
public void foo(){
    this.bar = 100;
}
```

Can I write a program that modifies the innards of this method, notices that it assigns a constant to a field, and turns it into the following:

```
public int baz = 100;

public void foo(){
    this.bar = baz;
}
```

Perhaps Java isn't really the language to do this kind of thing in - if not, I'm open to suggestions for languages that would allow me to basically reparse or inspect code in this way, and be able to alter it so precisely. I might be pipe dreaming here though, so please tell me if this is the case also.

Comment: In case anyone has come along to this - I haven't had a chance to test out these suggestions yet. I haven't forgotten about this though!

Comment: Use Lisp. Any other approach would be plainly wrong... Writing self-modifiable, polymorphic code is possible in a sensibe, OOP way *only* in Lisp dialects or heavily Lisp-influenced languages. OR use a scripting extension to Java with an equivalent to eval() function. I've written one, if you're interested. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a suggestion from a friend - Apache Commons' BCEL looks excellent:

http://commons.apache.org/bcel/manual.html

> The Byte Code Engineering Library (Apache Commons BCEL™) is intended to
>   give users a convenient way to analyze, create, and manipulate (binary)
>   Java class files (those ending with .class). Classes are represented by
>   objects which contain all the symbolic information of the given class:
>   methods, fields and byte code instructions, in particular.
>   Such objects can be read from an existing file, be transformed by a
>   program (e.g. a class loader at run-time) and written to a file again.
>   An even more interesting application is the creation of classes from
>   scratch at run-time. The Byte Code Engineering Library (BCEL) may be
>   also useful if you want to learn about the Java Virtual Machine (JVM)
>   and the format of Java .class files.

Comment: Isn't BCEL kinda dead nowadays?

Comment: No idea! Looks like an interesting project.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for software that allows you to do bytecode manipulation, there are several frameworks to achieve this, but the two most known currently are:

- [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)
- [javassist](http://www.javassist.org)

When performing bytecode modifications at runtime in Java classes keep in mind the following:

- If you change a class's bytecode after a class has been loaded by a classloader, you'll have to find a way to reload it's class definition (either through classloading tricks, or using hotswap functionalities)
- If you change the classes interface (example add new methods or fields) you will be able only to reach them through reflection.

Comment: If I wanted to make a lot of these modifications (say, 50 different modifications to the same class) and keep them separate, am I going to trip myself up managing them or is it easy to keep track of what's swapped in and so on?

Comment: @mtrc: Well since with bytecode manipulation you can do everything, you for instnace add a Java annotation to all the injected behavior so you can easily know what bytecode was injected

Comment: Interesting! What about the realities of reloading classes, though, is there a performance hit/stability issue with constnatly doing this?

Comment: @mtrc: I wouldn't see a stability issue, if you inject wrong bytecode things will get messed up yes, but if you inject things correctly you won't have problems. Regarding the performance hit, it will hit you and so will using reflection, you just have to see if the hit you take will be critical for your goal or is manageable, unfortunately I cannot give you numbers here. You can run a couple of tests by yourself though, just to see it, using for example javassist's HotSwapper http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/util/HotSwapper.html

Answer (score 0):

It's probably fair to say that Java wasn't designed with this purpose in mind, but you *can* do it potentially. How and when depends a little on the ultimate aim of the exercise. A couple of options:

- At the source code level, you can use the [Java Compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) to
  compile arbitrary code into a class file (which you can then load).
- At the bytecode level, you can write an agent that installs a
  [ClassFileTransformer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html) to arbitrarily alter a class "on the fly"
  as it is loaded. In practice, if you do this, you will also probably
  make use of a library such as [BCEL (Bytecode Engineering
  Library)](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/) to make manipulating the class easier.

Comment: It's probably fair to say that this answer was accurate about 10 years ago. Things change fast. For example, ASM is being packaged as part of JRE...

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
String script1 = "println(\"OK!\");";
eval( script1 );
script1 += "println(\"... well, maybe NOT OK after all\");";
eval( script2 );
```

Output:

```
OK!
OK!
... well, maybe NOT OK after all
```

... use a scripting extension to Java. Groovy and other things like that would probably allow you to do what you want. I've written a scripting extension which integrates with Java through reflection almost seamlessly myself; contact me if you're interested in the details.

Answer (score 0):

You want to investigate [program transformation systems (PTS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation), which provide general facilities for parsing and transforming languages at the source level.  PTS provide rewrite rules that say in effect, "if you see this pattern, replace it by that pattern" using the surface syntax of the target language.  This is done using full parsers so the rewrite rule really operates on language syntax and not text; such rewrite rules obviously won't attempt to modify code-like text in comments, unlike tools based on regexps.

Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit is one of these.  It provides not only the usual parsing, AST building and prettyprinting  (reproducing compilable source code complete with comments), but also supports symbol tables and control and data flow analysis.  These are needed for almost any interesting transformations.  DMS also has front ends for a variety of dialects of Java as well as many other languages.

Bytecode transformers exist because they are much easier to build; it is pretty easy to "parse" bytecode.   Of course, you can't make permanent source changes with a bytecode transformer, so it is lot less useful.